# PHP Certificate Authentication

Tags: php, validation, curl, ssl-certificate

I've been asked to create a data exchange between two servers. The client is hot on security and wants a high security handshake to confirm the identity before proceeding. Their advisor suggested a private / public key certificate to authenticate the transfer.

Exporting the data is fine. I've written many cURL scripts to send data to other servers using a public / private key system and I've already written the cURL for this system. The problem is handling the received certificate and authenticating it. I cannot find anything which relates to this type of transfer.

The cURL we will use to send data is

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certificate);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'PEM');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $certificatePass);
```

My problem is how to request the certificate in the response php file and verify the private certificate with the public key. Can anyone help?